# What does one do when MacBook Pro 2017 not recognizing thumb drive needed to boot startup?

Tags: mac, disk-utility, bootable-disk, macos

I wiped my 2017 MBP's drive at the direction of Apple support, to start fresh on my MacBook and try to eliminate/pinpoint a battery drain issues...now there is no bootable disk on the MPB.

I went through the procedures to download MAC OS High Sierra onto a thumb drive for use when booting the MBP...but the MBP is not recognizing the thumb drive.

When I start the MBP with <kbd>Cmd-R</kbd>, I get a progress bar for 2 seconds and then and error message that reads:
Picture: Triangle with ! on top of a globe
"apple.com/support
-3403F"

How can I get this MBP booted and running when it won't connect and reinstall from internet and also refuses to recognize thumb drive with Mac OS? Help!!!

Comment: Hold Opt, not Cmd/R

Comment: Thank you. I had tried all of the combinations of keys while booting computer but it turns out that the downloading of the OS had not completed on the thumb drive. It was there but thumb didn't eject properly due to a process of ejecting it had to do itself...if that makes any sense. I finally figured that out, got the other Mac to startup from it and everything is working now. Thx.